# CodeIgniter: Call to a member function contents() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I recently upgraded my 2.x CodeIgniter app to the RC of 3.0. Everything is running fine on my local machine.

But when I throw it up on a remote server when I try to call:

```
$this -> cart -> contents();
```

I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function contents() on a non-object in ...
```

If I

```
var_dump($this->cart)
```

on my local machine I get the expected cart object returned, but the same returns

```
NULL
```

when run on my remote server.

I also have a extension class for cart, which is just this:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Cart extends CI_Cart
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->product_name_rules = '\d\D';
        $this->product_id_rules = '\d\D';
    }
}
```

If I delete the MY_Cart.php file (above code) from my libraries folder I will get the same
Call to member function contents() on a non-object that I do on my remote server. Why would removing my own cart extension cause the cart object to cease to exist?

Any insight as to what might be causing this behavior, I've tried asking on the CodeIgniter forums with no luck.

Both my local machine and remote server are running PHP 5.4.17.

Here is a stack trace:

```
"…bss_web/public/development.bluesea.com/public/application/controllers/
cart.php (32) in Cart::add called at ? (?)"



//increment quantity by 1 if PN is already in cart
$qty = 1;
$items = $this->cart->contents(); //line 32
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    if ($item['id'] == $pid) {
        $qty = $item['qty'] + 1;
    }
}
```

…home/bss_web/public/development.bluesea.com/public/system/core/
CodeIgniter.php (356)

```
/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Call the requested method
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */

call_user_func_array(array(&$CI, $method), $params); // Line 356
```

…e_once called at /home/bss_web/public/development.bluesea.com/public/
index.php (312)

```
/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 */
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php'; //line 312
```

EDIT: I found out if I rename my controller in which this is failing in, to something other than 'Cart' (which it currently is) this seems to work. Shouldn't CodeIgniter avoid this conflict? Or why would this only be conflicting on my remote machine?

Comment: make sure you're loading the cart library either in your controller or in config/autoload.php

Comment: it is autoloading. which is why it works locally, i have also tried to load the library in the controllers method, both return the same non-object error

Answer (score 0):

```
function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->library('cart');
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean to put this in MY_cart

Can't call the class there: 'PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function library() on a non-object in'.

I am 'autoloading' the cart library, and I have also tried loading it right before I call $this->cart->content, both return the same non-object error.